# Formating xts date & time X2020.01.06.06.00.00

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I have an `xts` table all.transactions showing:

```
structure(list(Quantity = c(0, 162000, 149000, -149000)), row.names = c("X2020.01.06.06.00.00", 
"X2020.01.10.15.00.00", "X2020.02.03.15.00.00", "X2020.02.03.15.00.00.1"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I noticed that the index of XTS table would tend to change from `2020-01-06 06:00:00` to `X2020.01.06.06.00.00` when there are two record with the same time.

Is there a quick way to format/convert it back to normal (`2020-01-06 06:00:00`) please?

Comment: reproducible example please. How do you get to the xts table? aka what is the input?

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(all.transactions)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(all.transactions, 20))`.

Comment: Hi all, apologies, I didnt know about that dput tool, just discovered, thank you.

Comment: Duplicate times in time series don't make sense, what do you want to happen with duplicates?

Comment: jay.sf, your previous solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankyDoul Ok, I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row names are stored in the attributes of `tsx` named `"row.names"` and accessible with `attr()`. So one way is to format these attributes as time format.

```
attr(tsx, "row.names") <- as.character(strptime(attr(tsx, "row.names"), 
                                                format="X%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S"))
```

The problem, though, is that time series with duplicate row names are not valid. But maybe this solution is applicable to your real data.

---

*Data*

```
tsx <- structure(list(Quantity = c(0, 162000, 149000, -149000)), row.names = c("X2020.01.06.06.00.00", 
"X2020.01.10.15.00.00", "X2020.02.03.15.00.00", "X2020.02.03.15.00.00.1"
), class = "data.frame")
```